# Writev does not use MMAP for certain files?

Tags: apache, io, mmap

I have been reading about writev efficiency and came across a very interesting statement. I read that for certain files sizes, very small sizes(less than 16k) mmap is not executed when using writev. Is this allegation true? I have been searching for any mmap limits but haven't been able to find anything? For example if the file size is "X" then it will not execute, or anything similar to that. Any help is greatly appreciated.